# Dynamically adjust height of content using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a timeline and add content between time.
As I add content to articleContainerRight or articleContainerLeft I need background rectangle to dynamically adjust height and connect to circles which is maincontent.

here is my

CSS

```
.mainContent {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #666;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1em 5em 0;
    font: 32px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.mainContent::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0em;
  left: 0.72em;
  width: .2em;
  height:4em;
  background: #666;
  z-index: -1;
}

.mainContent:last-child::after {
  display: none;
}

.articleContainerRight{   
    position: relative;
    top: 1em;
    left: 17em;
    font: 15px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.articleContainerLeft{   
    position: relative;
    top: 1em;
    right: -5em;
    font: 15px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.articleContainer{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.spanContainer{
    color: blue;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="mainContent">1</div>
<div class="articleContainerRight">
    <div class="articleContainer">
        <span class="spanContainer">test1</span>
    </div>
     <div class="articleContainer">
        <span class="spanContainer">test12</span>
    </div>
     <div class="articleContainer">
        <span class="spanContainer">test13</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mainContent">2</div>
<div class="articleContainerLeft">
    <div class="articleContainer">
        <span class="spanContainer">test2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="articleContainer">
        <span class="spanContainer">test20</span>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="mainContent">3</div>
```

Comment: Could you submit an image that show what you want to get?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, with only pure CSS it is not possible to make a property adjust dynamically to e.g. another element's property. There is `em` that is depending on the font, percentage values and the fact, that parent elements usually always grow to contain their children, which makes it perfect to use the articleContainers in your example.

So to solve this particular problem I would use the `border-left` property of the `.articleContainerRight` and `border-right` for `.articleContainerLeft` respectively to extend the line created in the :after statement, as the border automatically grows with its element. If you then experiment a little bit with the margins and paddings of the main- and articleContainers you can manage it to be connected independently of their height in every situation.

The changes I made to get your example to work:

```
.mainContent {
    ...
    margin: 0 5em;
    ...
}

.articleContainerRight {
    ...
    left: 12em;
    border-left: 6px solid #666;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding-left: 4em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.articleContainerLeft {
    ...
    border-right: 6px solid #666;
    width: 110px;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

And the complete updated snippet:

```css
.mainContent {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #666;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 5em;
    font: 32px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.mainContent::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0em;
  left: 0.72em;
  width: .2em;
  height:4em;
  background: #666;
  z-index: -1;
}

.mainContent:last-child::after {
  display: none;
}

.articleContainerRight{   
    position: relative;
    top: 1em;
    left: 12em;
    font: 15px Arial, sans-serif;
    border-left: 6px solid #666;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding-left: 4em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.articleContainerLeft{   
    position: relative;
    top: 1em;
    right: -5em;
    font: 15px Arial, sans-serif;
    border-right: 6px solid #666;
    width: 110px;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.articleContainer{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.spanContainer{
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContent">1</div>
<div class="articleContainerRight">
    <div class="articleContainer">
        <span class="spanContainer">test1</span>
    </div>
  <div class="articleContainer">
        <span class="spanContainer">test12</span>
    </div>
     <div class="articleContainer">
        <span class="spanContainer">test13</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mainContent">2</div>
<div class="articleContainerLeft">
    <div class="articleContainer">
        <span class="spanContainer">test2</span>
    </div>
 <div class="articleContainer">
        <span class="spanContainer">test20</span>
    </div>
    
</div>
<div class="mainContent">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `border-left` in `.articleContainerRight & .articleContainerLeft` instead of `::after`.

Check this (I've updated .articleContainerRight styles): http://jsfiddle.net/Lyvdbtxo/